# Кроссдоменная сессия. Flask

Tags: python, flask

Как в `flask` сделать кроссдоменную сессию? то есть чтобы можно было читать сессию одного сайта сделанного на `flask` с другого?

Comment: Никак, потому что такой возможности нет в браузерах и flask тут ни при чём. Можно разве что с поддоменами попытаться что-нибудь придумать, но и то не факт

Comment: а что можно с поддоменами?

Comment: яваскриптом получить идентификатор с одного сайта, передать его на другой и через общий редис дернуть сессию

Comment: @eri фласк-сессии по умолчанию хранятся целиком в куках, так что идентификатора не существует и дёргать нечего :(

Comment: Идентификатор можно добавить.